# Reducing the cost of a Stream Analytics Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Basically I have a Stream Analytics Cluster 36RU/S and I am being billed for the total computer per hour even if I dont use any or  all of it.

I was wondering can I reduce my cost by stopping specific jobs or do you have any other suggestions for reducing the cost of a cluster.

I need the Stream Analytics Cluster and not a Stream Analytics Job because it must be in a VNET.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a ASA cluster, there are dedicated VMs that get provisioned and managed for you behind the scenes. There is no way as of today to 'pause' unused SUs to prevent you from getting billed. If you need your ASA jobs to connect to resources that are in a VNET, you will need to use ASA cluster with private endpoints or consider using [managed identity with 'allow trusted services' option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/connect-job-to-vnet#managed-identity-authentication-with-allow-trusted-services-configuration).